# Flutter StreamProvider returns null object eventhough stream is returning objects

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var _db = FirestoreService();
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            StreamProvider(create:(context)=>_db.getItems(),
              catchError:(BuildContext context,e){
              print("Error:$e");
              return null;
              },
              updateShouldNotify:const ListEquality<Item>().equals),
          ],

          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: Catalog(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class Item{
      String name;
      double price;

      Item({this.name,this.price});

      Item.fromJSON(Map<String,dynamic> json)
      :name=json['name'],
      price=json['price'];

      factory Item.fromMap(Map data)
      {
        return Item(name: data['name'],price:data['price']);
      }

    }
    class FirestoreService{

      var _db = Firestore.instance;

      Stream<List<Item>> getItems()
      {
        return _db.collection('akurdi')
            .snapshots()
            .map((snapshot)=>snapshot.documents
            .map((document)=>Item.fromMap(document.data)).toList());
      }

    }

    class Catalog extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        var items = Provider.of<List<Item>>(context);

        print(items.length);

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index].name),
              trailing: Text(items[index].price.toString())
              );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Errors:

I/flutter (12444): The getter 'length' was called on null.

I/flutter (12444): Receiver: null

I/flutter (12444): Tried calling: length

When i debug the code specially the getItems() function ,
I see the actual values from the firestore database but when i use the provider

var items = Provider.of>(context)
 to get the values,it returns null.

Comment: can you try after removing following line. updateShouldNotify:const ListEquality<Item>().equals? data is display after getting error or not? because initially there is no data in stream because of that error appear.

Comment: Yes initially i didn't use Updateshouldnotify ,but still it didn't work

Comment: data is display after getting error or not? because initially there is no data in stream because of that error appear.

Comment: No data is being displayed ,it simply returns the error that list builder is called will length 0(null)

Comment: Is it necessary to provide initial data ,because in my case whenever the app will be build for the first time,it call the stream provider and asks for List<Item> stream which would further invoke a call to firestore database,So i think it will be intialized with the data which is received from the stream

Comment: it is not necessary to provide, it is totally depends on you. what you want to show when no data is available. if you provide initial data then that data will be displayed until actual data arrives.

Comment: Now I have provided the initial data ,it displays only initial data but then after it doesn't update it with the real data from firestore

Comment: Thankyou so much  for the help,,,now it is working, By the way what actuall messes up if we use updateshousldnotify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **updateShouldNotify** is the real problem here. until that condition is not true, data will not change.

Just simply remove that updateShouldNotify and it will work.

You can use it when you want to control when should data has to be change. for example any new data added or remove then you can compare previous and current data length and update accordingly.